# To add custom data attributes in pushnotification using Amazon SNS

Tags: c#, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am  working on sending push-notification using Amazon SNS to all mobile platforms by attaching custom data in it.The data which  I generated is in  valid json format.Hereby i Attach my json input for push-notification with custom data.

But at the receiving IOS end they are receiving only alert response and they are not receiving custom data. Hereby I attach the json data what I generated:

Json input data:

```
{
    "default": "thirdcustomcheck",
    "aps": {
        "alert": "thirdcustomcheck",
        "sound": "mailsent.wav"
    },
    "acme1": "checkingData",
}
```

Response received in IOS is given below:

```
{
    aps = {
        alert = thirdcustomcheck;
    };
}
```

I am using publish-request attribute in Amazon SNS to push the notification.

Please help me out regarding this.  Thanx in advance......

Comment: any updates on this